# How does amazon ec2 work in regards to routing a domain name to an instance using load balancers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, aws-security-group, amazon-elb

How does amazon ec2 work in regards to routing a domain name to an instance using load balancers?

What is the flow of a request from the domain name to the ec2 instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is documentation regarding this on AWS, you can check the page [Routing traffic to an ELB load balancer - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html) which contains the details.

Moreover in the above document there are links to other pages like how to use Route 53 etc., you will get full coverage of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The flow of traffic is as shown below.

> Hosted zone => Load balancer => Target group => EC2 Instance.

1. So when you make a request to a domain name the request is routed following the "rules" that are in its [hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-working-with.html).

> A hosted zone is a container for records, and records contain
> information about how you want to route traffic for a specific domain,
> such as example.com, and its subdomains (acme.example.com,
> zenith.example.com). A hosted zone and the corresponding domain have
> the same name.

2. In one of the rules that you set in the hosted zone there should be a rule(a record) that directs traffic from your domain name to the load balancer. The record is of '[A type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#AFormat)'.The load balancer then routes the traffic to the target group.

> A load balancer distributes incoming application traffic across
> multiple EC2 instances in multiple Availability Zones. ... Elastic
> Load Balancing detects unhealthy instances and routes traffic only to
> healthy instances. Your load balancer serves as a single point of
> contact for clients.

3. The target group then has records called targets. This targets store information like `EC2 instance id`, `port`, `health status` among others. The target info informs how traffic is routed. If the `health status` is unhealthy traffic is routed to a target with a healthy status or an error is returned as a response.

> A target group tells a load balancer where to direct traffic to : EC2
> instances, fixed IP addresses; or AWS Lambda functions, amongst
> others. When creating a load balancer, you create one or more
> listeners and configure listener rules to direct the traffic to one
> target group.

4. When traffic is routed from the target group to a healthy target it goes to the EC2 instance that the `EC2 instance id` belongs to. In the EC2 instance there should be a server running that takes the request and gives back the appropriate response.

> An Amazon EC2 instance is a virtual server in Amazon's Elastic Compute
> Cloud (EC2) for running applications on the Amazon Web Services (AWS)
> infrastructure.